# How to make a button flash using .after in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner and am making a simple Simon game using Tkinter and Python. I have the logic figured out, however, I'm really struggling getting buttons to flash to show the player the sequence. What I'm doing here is having it loop through the button sequence, as it loops through, it will flash the correct buttons accordingly. However, no matter what I do I cannot get the button to flash white, that is, it seemingly skips the configure method that changes the bg to white, and only does the configure that changes the bg to red/blue/green/yellow.

I tested this in a simple program that is supposed to flash a label after I press a button, but same story. It just won't do the first configure and only seems to do the second. So if I tell it to change the label to white, then wait 200 ms, then change it to blue, it will only change it to blue after 200 ms.

```py
        for x in cpu_sequence:

            if x == "A":
                a_butt.after(200)
                a_butt.configure(bg="white")
                a_butt.after(200)
                a_butt.configure(bg="red")


            elif x == "B":
                b_butt.after(200)
                b_butt.configure(bg="white")
                b_butt.after(200)
                b_butt.configure(bg="green")


            elif x == "C":
                c_butt.after(200)
                c_butt.configure(bg="white")
                c_butt.after(200)
                c_butt.configure(bg="blue")


            elif x == "D":
                d_butt.after(200)
                d_butt.configure(bg="white")
                d_butt.after(200)
                d_butt.configure(bg="yellow")
```

It should wait 200 ms, change the button to white, then wait 200 ms, then change the button back to its original color (red, green, blue, or yellow).

Comment: When you set something in GUI then it doesn't redraw element on screen at once but it waits till you end your function and then `mainloop()` redraw all changes in one moment. You may use `root.update()` after every `configure()` to manually redraw elements in window. BTW: because you changed to white, next to blue so finally `mainloop()` see `blue` and it redraw widget with blue color.

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Comment: You really should not need `update()`. Tkinter handles updates just fine if you build your function correctly. From what I can see in your code you are trying to use `after()` like `sleep()` and after does not work like that. `after()` is used to call something after a set time so you need to also provide something to call. IE: `after(200, func_name)`.

Comment: I'll try to implement a function instead because I can see it's pretty messy like this

Comment: If you provide a testable example I can rebuild it for you.

Answer (score 1):

`after` with a single argument is no different than calling `time.sleep` -- it causes the application to freeze. However, if you give `after` an argument other than just the number of milliseconds, it will call that argument as a function after the given delay.

If all you're wanting to do is change the background in 200ms, and then change it again 200ms after that (eg: 400ms after the function is called), you can schedule both of those commands at the same time. Tkinter will then call those functions at the appropriate time.

```
label.after(200, lambda: label.configure(background="white"))
label.after(400, lambda: label.configure(background="yellow"))
```

Note: `lambda` is used here because it's not possible to pass keyword arguments via `after`. `lambda` is a way to provide a nameless *callable* to `after`.  If we were calling a function that didn't need keyword arguments, `lambda` would be unnecessary.

For example:

```
def set_color(label, color):
    label.configure(background=color)

label.after(200, set_color, label, "white")
label.after(400, set_color, label, "yellow")
```

---

Here's a complete example:

```
import tkinter as tk
def flash():
    root.after(200, lambda: label.configure(background="white"))
    root.after(400, lambda: label.configure(background="yellow"))

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello", background="yellow")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Flash!", command=flash)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button.pack(side="bottom", padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is good to know. I did not know that `after()` if only a time was given acted like `sleep()`. Something to look out for when trouble shooting.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: One question, since I have 4 total buttons I'd want to flash depending on the character the For loop comes across, how would I be able to use a single flasher function for flashing each button? How would I be able to pass the button I want to flash to the flasher function? Really new at this so I apologize if that doesn't make any sense.